# Is my VHDL 1-bit Behavioral ALU complete?

Tags: vhdl, alu

This is my first time writing VHDL code, and I'm wondering if this simple ALU VHDL code is complete. Everything I can find is for more complex ALUs, but I just need to write this simple one.

The problem is as follows:

Write a behavioral model that represents a simple ALU with integer inputs and 
output, and a function select input of type bit.  If the function select is ‘0’, the ALU 
output should be the sum of the inputs; otherwise the output should be the difference of 
the inputs.

```
entity ALU is
    port(x, y, func: in bit; z: out bit;);
end entity ALU;

architecture behav of ALU is
begin
    alu: process is
    begin
        case func is
            when "0" =>
                z <= x + y;
                wait on x, y;
            when "1" =>
                z <= x - y;
                wait on x, y;
        end case;
    end process;
end behav;
```

I'm not asking for a complete solution, rather just to know whether my code is everything I will need for this simple problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will fail if the inputs `x` and `y` do not change, but the operator `func` does.

That being said,  in all of the VHDL code I've ever seen, you would just use a sensitivity list instead of the wait statements.

```
process(func, x, y)
begin
    case func is
        when "0" =>
            z <= x + y;
        when "1" =>
            z <= x - y;
    end case;
end process;
```

or, if you are using VHDL-2008:

```
process(all)
begin
    case func is
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I see what you mean now that you mention sensitivity lists - that would be more practical than wait. I'll implement that instead.

Comment: @Drac: The difference in your and sharth's process is not just a matter of practicality, it also determines what can be synthesized into hardware or not. I don't think the process with the wait statements will synthesize into what you want, if it will even synthesize at all.  The code in this answer is a very standard method of implying combinatorial logic, which in this case is a 2-input mux.